# UAC issue on Windows Server 2008 R2

Tags: batch-file, compatibility, windows-server-2008-r2, uac

I have a 20-year-old executable on 64-bit Windows 2008 R2 that needs to run when called from a batch file.
I tried the settings under Compatibility | Privilege Level | Change settings for all users | Run this program as an administrator, but it does not work -- it always brings up the UAC access prompt.

The only way it will run is with User Account Control disabled.  I thought about running the batch in a Scheduled Task with the elevated permissions, but if it doesn't work with the Compatibility settings to run as admin, I don't know how it would be any different in Scheduled Tasks.  I will be running it with Scheduled Tasks, but right now I am in testing mode.

Also, the paths are hard-coded in the program, so I can't reinstall under Program Files - it has to be directly under C: drive.

Is there something else I can do to get this to run with UAC enabled?

Comment: Note that the behaviour you describe for the "run this program as an administrator" compatibility option is as expected.  It isn't supposed to bypass the UAC prompt, just to make sure that Windows doesn't run the program without admin privilege.

Answer (score 2):

When you login to Windows with an Administrator account, Windows creates two tokens for you: an elevated one that has all your admin privileges, and a limited one that functions more like a regular user token. When the OS detects that you are trying to run something that requires the elevated privileges, it will show a UAC prompt to allow you to confirm that you want to run elevated.

So, if you run the batch file in a way that it already uses an elevated token, you won't get a UAC prompt. Interactively, you can open Command Prompt elevated (which will require a UAC confirmation), and then run the batch file as much as you want without any further prompts. Alternatively, you could run it as a scheduled task. As long as the scheduled task is running with the correct user credentials (you could run under your user account with highest privileges checked, or run it under some system account, or even create a completely new Admin user account), it should be able to run without any UAC prompt.

Bear in mind that as soon as you have the system running a batch file with elevated privileges, anyone who can modify that batch file can compromise your computer. You should run it as an account with as few privileges as possible (while still running successfully), and make sure the batch file itself is secured.

Comment: +1.  Another option for the batch file is to run it via a shortcut, and set the "run as admin" option on the shortcut.

Comment: @HarryJohnston I believe that this will still pop up a UAC prompt, but it does make it so you don't have to right-click and choose "Run as Administrator". It will also display the UAC shield on the icon so you know it is an admin link.

Comment: Yes, of course.  You always have to approve the UAC prompt, unless you've set it up as a scheduled task (or another similar method).

Comment: Thank you all for the helpful comments.  I created a Scheduled Task to run the batch file every 5 minutes with Highest Privileges, and it now seems to be running fine.

Comment: Just a followup: part of the issue here is that there are really 2 batch files (let's call them A.bat & B.bat).
A.bat passes variables and parameters in a call to B.bat. Then B.bat calls various other batch files and several exe files.  I have right-clicked A.bat and selected Run As Administrator, but that does not get passed to B.bat and its subsequent calls. By the way, I am always logged in as administrator when working on this server.

Comment: Final followup: since this will run only as a scheduled task without triggering the UAC prompt, I simply created a shortcut to the task (C:\Windows\System32\schtasks.exe /run /tn "Call_Batch") and I can now run my tests manually with only one initial prompt.